# Why does typescript require me to workaround setting a value of type boolean?

Tags: typescript, type-conversion, boolean

```
function f1()
{
    const v : string = String();

    if(v) {alert("IF");} // OK

    const b : boolean = v; // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

    if(b) {alert("BOOLEAN");}
}

f1();
```

Now my solution to this problem is the double exclamation mark but I smell trouble or am I wrong:

```
    const b : boolean = !!v; //OK
```

I'm using this quide as a [base](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter).

Comment: Well, because string is not a boolean :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a type safety decision. You can use any type in `if` (or other places where conditions are expected such as `while` or `?:`) as this works in JS and is common practice.

If you declare a variable explicitly of type `boolean`, that means you want to constrain the possible values to `true` or `false` (and `undefined` and `null` if you don't use `strictNullChecks`). Since Typescript performs no runtime conversions, if your assignment were allowed, `b` would contain a `string`. Sure it would work the same if used in conditionals but `===` might yield unexpected results for example.

Converting a type of any value to `boolean` using double negation (`!!`) is common in JS and it is fine to use.

Comment: I was worried since for example in C++ you could overload the `!` operator - I guess I was wrong.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions You can't overload operators in JS (fortunately ?) so that will work as expected (well unless you override `valueOf` https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/05/03/the-value-of-valueof/)